# Satisfying SQLite constraint with Java JDBC queries

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

I have a SQLite database where a table "Transactions" contains an ID field which is a primary key and is autoincremented.

```
CREATE TABLE transactions (
  id        int AUTO_INCREMENT not null,
  time      DATETIME not null,
  buyer         varchar(320) not null,
  seller        varchar(320) not null,
  price         float not null,
  size      int not null,
  currency  char(3) not null,
  symbol        varchar(10) not null,
  primary key (id)
);
```

I have created a Java class to handle SQL queries.

```
            try {
                PreparedStatement pStmt = db.getConnection().prepareStatement(
                        "INSERT INTO transactions( id, time, buyer, seller, price, size, currency, symbol ) " +
                                "VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? )"
                );

                java.util.Date uDate = sdf.parse( curLine[0] );

                try {

                    pStmt.setLong( 2, uDate.getTime() );
                    pStmt.setString( 3, curLine[1] );
                    pStmt.setString( 4, curLine[2] );
                    pStmt.setFloat( 5, Float.parseFloat( curLine[3] ) );
                    pStmt.setInt( 6, Integer.parseInt( curLine[4] ) );
                    pStmt.setString( 7, curLine[5] );
                    pStmt.setString( 8, curLine[6] );

                    pStmt.executeUpdate();

                } catch( SQLException e ) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            } catch ( SQLException e ) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

curLine is an array of values parsed from a CSV file.

At runtime, I have the following error

> org.sqlite.SQLiteException: [SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_NOTNULL]  A NOT NULL constraint failed (NOT NULL constraint failed: transactions.id)

I don't know how to handle it.

I have tried several other configurations:

- Don't indicate the "id" field in the sql query.
- Give a 0 value to "id".

But each of these configurations raise an error.

Comment: pretty self-explanatory, you're passing `null` to a parameter for a column which does not accept `null` (currently, any column). Without showing more code it's hard to say which but overall it's likely the array is initialized without having a specific index set (and thus defaults to null). This is the point where you debug your code (add print statements and see current values being passed).

Comment: But I don't want to pass any value to `id` because it's an auto increment field. So i'd like it to behave like a normal auto increment field.

Comment: Are you executing the CREATE TABLE statement yourself, or is it supposed to be the DDL for an already-existing SQLite table?

Comment: @GordThompson The table is created separately in a terminal process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `id` from your insert statement to give sql a chance to use its own process to auto-increment:

```
"INSERT INTO transactions( time, buyer, seller, price, size, currency, symbol ) " +
                            "VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? )"
```

**EDIT 1**

Please use SQLite compliant syntax for your table creation:

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE t2 ( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, size INTEGER NOT NULL);
sqlite> INSERT INTO t2 ( size) VALUES (123);
sqlite> INSERT INTO t2 ( size) VALUES (456);
sqlite> SELECT * FROM t2;
1|123
2|456
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I have the following error `[SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_NOTNULL]  A NOT NULL constraint failed (NOT NULL constraint failed: transactions.id)`
I have tried to remove the not null constraints from the SQL schema but it leads to an empty field (the autoincrement doesn't occur)

Comment: Well... are you sure you use SQLLite? Because the syntax is SQLLite is `column1 INTEGER AUTOINCREMENT`, not `id int AUTO_INCREMENT not null,`

Comment: Also why don't you have a `PRIMARY KEY`?

Comment: @PierreP. Don leave out the first Prepared Statement Value `pStmt.setLong( 1`. Than this solution should work. For auto-increment values there are two ways. Set them to a distinct value or leave them completely out in the insert.

Comment: Please double check your code. You also have to adjust your `set` statements for `PreparedStatement`

Comment: @bc004346 I have a primary key. And the syntax in SQLite is AUTO_INCREMENT, not AUTOINCREMENT. 
@notes-jj I don't get what you mean. The `id`field is an integer value and I don't find any method from the PreparedStatement class that allow me to bind a value to an AUTO_INCREMENT not null primary field.

Comment: Yes it is [AUTOINCREMENT](http://sqlite.org/autoinc.html) What version are you using? Is it some custom flavor of SQLLite?

Comment: @bc004346 I'm using a pre-installed SQLite version on Mac OS X 
`3.14.0 2016-07-26 15:17:14 91e811f51e611a37372875e96a4c51bbed2dfdea`

Comment: @PierreP. - Sorry, but no, for SQLite it's `AUTOINCREMENT` and it's only valid in the context of `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT` when creating the table. (`AUTO_INCREMENT` is MySQL.)

Comment: @PierreP. Start the insert without the id `"INSERT INTO transactions( time, ...` like bc004346 said. Then start the chain of parameters with `1` --> `pStmt.setLong( 1, uDate.getTime() `. As much questions mark you have in your expression as much numbers there have to be in the prepared statement. 7 question marks mean ID `1` ... `7`, don't leave any ID out.

Answer (score 1):

@bc004346 answer is correct. I'll add some details here.

This demonstrates the problem you have:

```
sqlite> create table a (id int AUTO_INCREMENT not null, v varchar(5));
sqlite> insert into a (v) values ('a');
Error: NOT NULL constraint failed: a.id
sqlite> drop table a;
sqlite> create table a (id integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, v varchar(5));
sqlite> insert into a (v) values ('a');
sqlite> select * from a;
1|a
```

The problem you face is caused by the way [types work](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) in sqlite. Type is associated with value itself not with a column. As a consequence of this typename for column in create table has very little meaning and even can be omitted completely.

This is a valid table definition in sqlite:

```
create table a(x, y);
```

You can specify basically any sequence of tokens as a type name:

```
sqlite> create table e (id int xxxx xxx not null, v varchar(5));
sqlite> create table f (id int xxxx xxx yyyy not null, v varchar(5));
sqlite> create table g (id inteeeee xxxx xxx yyyy not null, v varchar(5));
sqlite> create table h (id what ever you want not null, v varchar(5));
```

Having this in mind you can see that the definition you specified for table `transactions` does not work the way you expect, namely column id is not autoincrement column and is treated as regular column with `not null` constraint . If you do not specify a value in insert statement for it you get constraint violation.

To overcome this you either need to use correct syntax to create `AUTOINCREMENT` field or manually generate id column value and set it during insert.